# Debugging in Eclipse on MacOS X slow - anything that I can do?

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, debugging, eclipse-kepler

on my Mac debugging in Eclipse is extremly slow. With slow I mean stepping through the code. Every step (even if it is only multiline string-concatenation) takes about 1-2 seconds. When I compare that to eclipse running on Windows, that is just painful!

I'm using Eclipse Kepler with Sun JDK 1.7.0_45 (as Eclipse Runtime and Program Runtime). Switching to Apple JDK 6 did not change that much. Is there anything that I can do about that?

**Edit:**

What I'm trying to do is to debug a local application using Debug As > Java Application.

My eclipse.ini is looking like this:

```
-startup
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
-vm
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
--launcher.library
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_1.1.200.v20130807-1835
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.IEVersion=10001
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-Xms40m
-Xmx2048m
-Xdock:icon=../Resources/Eclipse.icns
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
```

Comment: Depends. Are you debugging locally, or connected via JDWP to a remote JVM?

Comment: I'm trying to debug a local java application using Debug As > Java Application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Increase the amount of memory for your JVM. Open eclipse.ini from the following path:

> Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse.ini

. Edit the following variables like so. Replace 1.6 with your version of Java.

```
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion = 1.6
-Xms128m
-Xmx1024m
```

Comment: Basically you we're on the right track. It was not the Xmx or Xms Settings that caused my problem. In my eclipse.ini there are two entries in there:   
    --launcher.XXMaxPermSize 256m
and
    -XX:MaxPermSize=512m

It seems that the -XX:MaxPermSize was ignored and eclipse started using a MaxPermSize of 256m. After changing that line, debugging is now possible without a headache.

Answer (score 2):

The actual problem was a little bit unexpected: In the eclipse.ini there were two settings:

```
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
```

and

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

For some reason eclipse preferred the 256m MaxPermSize setting. After changing that line to 512m everything works nice and fast. *sigh* software development tooling can be boring. Thanks for any responses to this question!

Answer (score 0):

Remove all breakpoint definitions once and then restart it by adding the ones you need only.
Sometimes Eclipse is getting out of synch with some of its internal/displayed state.